# Java: Parsing a Large File Size:NumberFormatException

Tags: java, parsing, csv, numberformatexception

I have a large .csv file of over 45 MB in memory with around  45000 rows and 30  Columns , I would like to parse this file efficiently and i am incurring numerous problems with i have never incurred when i parsed much smaller(800kb 1000 rows ,30 Columns) files more efficiently without any problem

I am incurring NumberFormatExceptions when i choose to intake the values of  KVP column

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "KVP"
```

Please let me know the reason for these Numberformatexceptions..Any clue is greatly appreciated

Comment: Which number would you expect `KVP` to be translated to?

Comment: As per Exception it clear that what you except in "KVP" is not a number format. like it may be any String like a,b,c or any special char.

Comment: KVP is a column in CSV file consisting of 45000 Values, I would like to take all the Values from CSV file and store in Arraylist, but when i debug i see that the code for parser that i have written is unable to intake the values from a Larger CSV file , compared to smaller one

Comment: very likely you've chosen the correct the number column, but the first row was label, `"KVP"`, so you should skip the title/header/label line.

Comment: you are probably trying to pare the title of the column `"KVP"` as a number. Just skip the first row of column titles when parsing numbers/values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you forgot to skip the first line which is not number but string in  column "KVP"